# On dataflow inside data factory pricing

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, dataflow

We are analyzing the option to use dataflow inside Data Factory but we are having some questions that cannot find the answer.

How much does it costs?

We are on a tight budget and not sure if this tool is the right one for our needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use the Azure Pricing Calculator, its a really practical tool to check how much each product costs. You can configure everything from any resource you can create and check the monthly cost. Simply type Data Factory in the search bar, click and scroll down to configure the data flow options.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/calculator/

Note that you pay per use, so you will never be using 730 hours a month!! It may look expensive when you see it that way. 10 hours per month is what we use internally to calculate when we are not sure how much it will take.

If its the right tool for your needs or not, will depend on your specific needs. Data factory on its own just moves data around, whereas with dataflow it can modify it on the fly.

Comment: What do you mean with "just moves data around"?

Comment: I mean it cannot modify the data it moves. You are limited in your options without dataflow when you want to do modifications. You can do some stuff when doing a select from a database, but other than that data factory will take the data, and store it on a supported sink without much modifications to it. Dataflow is what allows you to modify it.

Answer (score 2):

Data Factory data flows are visually-designed components inside of Data Factory that enable data transformations at scale. You pay for the data flow cluster execution and debugging time per vCore-hour. The minimum cluster size to run a data flow is 8 vCores. Execution and debugging charges are prorated by the minute and rounded up. While in preview, data flow is offered with a preview discount.

- Type: **Compute Optimized**

  - Price: $0.072 per vCore-hour
  - Description: Data flow built on Compute Optimized compute
- Type: **General Purpose**

  - Price: $0.104 per vCore-hour
  - Description: Data flow built on General Purpose compute
- Type: **Memory Optimized**

  - Price: $0.138 per vCore-hour
  - Description: Data flow built on Memory Optimized compute

More available at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-factory/data-pipeline/

Note that this is in **PREVIEW** so final price (when released to GA) might change.